# Getting Rectangles stacked vertically to horizontally but keeping shape

Tags: c#

I have the input done correctly all my rectangles are stacked vertically and have different colors each time a new rectangle is drawn, but I am struggling to get the output to look like the bottom pic. Please can anybody help put me on the right path.

[image: rectangles]

```
    //List to strore all randomly generated rectangles
    List<Rectangle> rectangleCollection = new List<Rectangle>();
    //Counts the amount of time a rectangle needs to be drawn
    int count = 0;

    public static Random ran = new Random();

    void CreateRectangle()
    {
        int TallestRectangle = 0; ;


        int PrevRecY = 0;

        Graphics graphic = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
        SolidBrush brush;

        foreach (Rectangle rect in rectangleCollection)
        {
            if (rect.Height > TallestRectangle)
                TallestRectangle = rect.Height;
        }

        foreach (Rectangle rect in rectangleCollection)
        {
            graphic.FillRectangle(brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(ran.Next(1, 255), ran.Next(1, 255), ran.Next(1, 255))),
                new Rectangle(rect.X + PrevRecY, (TallestRectangle - rect.Height), rect.Width, rect.Height));

            PrevRecY += rect.Width;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        count = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            GetRandomRectangle();
        }
        CreateRectangle();
    }

    void GetRandomRectangle()
    {
        Graphics graph = this.CreateGraphics();
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;

        int width = ran.Next(20, 100);
        int height = ran.Next(30, 150);

        Rectangle rec1 = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
        rectangleCollection.Add(rec1);
    }
```

Comment: and what did you tried? you code just generate problem

Comment: This question is not very clear and could use improvement, it's hard to understand what the specific problem you are having is - you say you are struggling but you don't identify with what.

Comment: A random set of rectangles placed next to each other, from left to right, on the same baseline. Output: Output the minimum number of vertically stacked rectangles that represents the same area and resulting shape as described by the input rectangles.

Comment: All you've done for @Amicable is reword the question. I think they want to know what you've tried so far. Generally this site works better if you have a specific problem you are solving, i.e. code that doesn't work etc. You shouldn't just ask "how do I do X?". I've given you a general approch. I suggest you try and code what I've described and if you have more specific questions make another post.

Comment: could you please tell me whats the reason to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

For each rectangle, ordered shortest to tallest,

- Make a horizontal rectangle of that height, starting from the left of all rectangles taller than that, ending at the right of all rectangles right of that.

Whenever you're creating a horizontal rectangle place it on top of the highest horizontal rectangle that is below (in terms of hiorizontal position) the one you're creating.

Comment: How would I arrange them from shortest to tallest?

Comment: You're not arranging them, just ordering them so you can loop. You can just compare `rectangle.Top` since they all start from the same bottom point